# cotangent bundles as symplectic manifolds

Tags: symplectic-geometry, tangent-bundle

Why do we always think of symplectic manifolds as locally being a contangent bundle, why not simply the tangent bundle, or even easier, why not just $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$?

Comment: Is the idea here that since a general symplectic manifold need not be a cotangent bundle globally (e.g., compact manifolds like $S^2$), you are asking why we bother to think of it as a cotangent bundles locally rather than simplifying all the way down to a tangent bundle or just $R^2$?  I'd like to hear from an expert, but my guess is that (1) $R^2$ doesn't come with a symplectic form and (2) the standard way for inducing a symplectic form from a tangent bundle is (I think) by first constructing the cotangent bundle.  Is that the flavor of answer you're looking for?

Answer (score 2):

I can only speak to the context that I see them, so this might not be as robust or deep as you'd like:

A lot of it comes from mechanics. Symplectic manifolds come from a generalization of phase space, which we view mathematically as the cotangent bundle (of configuration space). In fact, the cotangent bundle comes equipped with a canonical one-form $\theta$, and the exterior derivative $\sigma$ of this one-form provides the symplectic structure. The form $\sigma$ allows us to define e.g. Hamiltonian flow, which preserve the volume form under pullback. It is worth noting that Darboux's Theorem says, essentially, that all symplectic forms are equivalent to $\sigma$ on $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$, locally.

In short, relating symplectic manifolds to the cotangent bundle allow us to naturally define a lot of generalizations of and analogues to classical mechanics.